# Does manually setting NavicationController.viewControllers release the existing viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have code that replaces an entire stack of ViewControllers in a NavigationController, as sort of a "reset" that switches between a number of different threads of UI scenes. Instead of creating a different NavigationController for each flow in storyboard, I decided to just change the NavigationController.viewControllers array manually:

```
self.navController.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
```

What happens to the old stack of ViewControllers? Do they automatically get release/unloaded? or do they hang around forever and therefore causing memory leak?

Note:
I know about unwind segue, but I didn't want to use that since even if I unwound to the first VC in NavVC, I still have to replace it with a different VC, and setting .viewController is the only way I know to not result in a "Back button"

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the old stack of ViewControllers?

The `viewControllers` property points to an array and has copy semantics, so when you assign an array of view controllers to that property, the navigation controller copies the array. When you assign a different array to that property, the previous one will be deallocated (assuming there are no other strong references to it). The same is true for any of the view controllers in the array -- if nothing else has a strong reference to them, they will be deallocated. This is no different from any other Objective-C object.

Answer (score 0):

After you set the new view controllers, your `UINavigationController` will lose its strong reference to the old stack. If you do not have any remaining strong references to the items in the old stack, they will indeed be released by ARC.

One way to verify this behavior is to override `-(void)dealloc` in the view controllers you want released, and put some logging in there. you should be able to see when dealloc is called.